# How to get sum of rows where it matches the condition

Tags: sql-server, sum, sql-server-2017

I am trying to get the sum of the rows where it matches the condition. 
Suppose you have column a, b and a is consisted of arbitrary integers from 0 to 500.

Let's say there are 5 rows in the table I want to calculate from.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|           a         |          b       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |          4       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |          6       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |          8       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          9       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to get the sum of rows for each value in column A.
The result would be as below.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|           a         |        sum       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         10       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |          6       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select a, SUM(b) sum From Table
Group By a
```

Comment: totally forgotten the existence of group by statement. Thank you!